# How to change CSS class of a column based on the number of items in a JavaScript array?

Tags: javascript, angular

I want to change a CSS class like `col-md-12` based on the number of items in an array. I am pushing items to an array.

For example, when there is one item in the array, the class must be `col-md-12`, but when there are more items, the class must be `col-md-6`. There should be two columns with the class `col-md-6`.

```
<div class="row footer" *ngIf="model.component.length!=undefined">
    <div class="col-md-{{getNoOfCols(model.component.length)}}" *ngFor="let item of model.component" style="margin-top:-25px;">
        <all-component [model]="item" (Click1)="onComponentClick($event)" [selectedId]="targetBuilderId"></all-component>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what does your component code looks like?

Comment: you can use ng-class ...

Answer (score 0):

You can `ng-class`

Example :

```
ng-class="{
   'col-md-12' : (getNoOfCols(model.component.length) === 1),
   'col-md-6' : (getNoOfCols(model.component.length) > 1)
}"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ngIf to show divs according to your array length

```
<div class="row footer" *ngIf="model.component !=undefined">
    <div *ngIf="model.component.length < 2; else colSix">
        <div class="col-md-12">Code for col-md-12</div>
    </div>
    <ng-template #colSix>
        <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="col-md-6">
    </ng-template>    
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to avoid calling a function inside your template and use ngClass to switch between the classes

```
 import {Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';

  @Component({
  selector: 'sample-app',
  template: `
    <div class="row footer">
            <div *ngFor="let item of arr" 
            [ngClass]='{"col-md-12": arr.length == 1, "col-md-6": arr.length > 1}'
            >
            {{item}} hello
            </div>
     </div>
  `
  })
  export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  arr: any[];

  ngOnInit() {

    this.arr = ['item1', 'item2', 'item3'];
  }
  }
```